# List of organizations given an user id or username

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am trying to obtain a list of organizations that belongs an userId or username from the sonarcloud api. The uri I want to expose looks like https:///users/{userId,username}/organizations. Do you have any experience that complains this use case? I have explored almost all the documentation and I didn't find any solution.

Comment: SonarCloud exposes only the api/user_groups and api/user endpoints. Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: I studied the sonarcloud api,  and I didn't discover a way to obtain this data. I am asking because maybe somebody else could find another way that I didn't realize yet. Remember api documentation is not always the best. Thank you anyways for your response.

Comment: As of today, such API is not provided on SonarCloud.